# How can I add gradle-api library to my project?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have a **spring boot** project build with **Gradle**. When I `clean/build` project, I have these external libraries, marked as `library root`. And I can use it in my classes: `import org.gradle.api.tasks.*`

[image]

Now I create a new project, and these libraries absent. I don't understand how can I configure it. I want to use `import org.gradle.api.tasks.*` in a new project but I can't do it.

Comment: You should add the current project as Parent project to your new project in its build.gradale file

Comment: these are different projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add the "gradleApi" into your new project dependencies :

```
dependencies {   
    implementation gradleApi()
}
```

See : https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html#gradleApi--

Comment: it helps! But how can it work in my first project if I haven't this dependency in first project?

Comment: maybe you have a plugin applied to your first project, that brings this dependency. (some plugins like `java-gradle-plugin` do that, for example)